# How to evenly trim a mustache in front of a mirror?

Tags: personal-care, efficiency

I often trim my mustache in front of a mirror and it always confuses me which side of the mustache I am currently trimming,  which then leads to an unbalanced mustache.  Is there a life hack for this problem to get an even line?

Comment: You may also want to check the answers here: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/how-do-i-trim-my-facial-hair-symmetrically-and-the-same-every-time
It's a more general question discussing all facial hair. Maybe something helps. I still need to try all these methods out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're relatively young and new to trimming your mustache. The only real solution to this problem is practice. In time you get used to allowing for the reversal that a mirror gives you and your mustache will come out straighter.

Answer (score 1):

A guide (such as a comb) will help you out.

For example, if you want to trim your mustache straight across, place an ordinary comb through it, parallel to the floor (like a shelf). In the mirror, make sure it looks level. Then, trim all the hairs underneath the comb, making sure to keep the comb level in the mirror the whole time.

If you want a more complicated mustache, put the comb on the right half, for example, and make sure it is exactly where you want it. Then cut off all the hair underneath the comb. Move the comb to the left side of your mustache, make sure it looks perfectly-placed in the mirror, and then trim off all the hair underneath it.